# Laravel scheduled task: cron syntax for 'every 2 minutes' is ignored

Tags: laravel

I'am using the following syntax

```
$schedule->job(new PublishHighlightPlan())->cron('* */2 * * *');
```

Actually my job is executed every *single* minute, not *every two* as I expect.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are making every 2nd hours as per your syntax.
Try below pattern.

```
$schedule->job(new PublishHighlightPlan())->cron('*/2 * * * *');
```

It might help you.

Comment: :( Thanks... and sorry